# dpkg-query: error: unknown option --status-fd Use --help for help about querying packages. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: dpkg

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
I am not able to install any package or not able to execute "sudo apt upgrade" successfully. Everytime i am getting following error:

```
dpkg-query: error: unknown option --status-fd

Use --help for help about querying packages.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

By mistake i have removed snap also. so not able to install any snap app.
I have tried following also but error is same:

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg`
2. `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

   `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. `sudo fsck /dev/sdX`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a few lines of context above and below the `unknown option --status-fd` error.